# How to credit Firebase and Android Support Library?

Tags: android, firebase, android-support-library, credits, attribution

I use Firebase in my Android project:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
```

I have an about/credits activity. Here I show licensing info about projects I use in my app. Where can I find this info for Firebase?

I also use Android Support Library. Do I need to credit somebody/something?

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can get "Terms of Use" for Firebase on this [page](https://firebase.google.com/terms/)

Actually, you don't need to give credit for using Android Support Library.

Comment: Could you provide source(s) supporting your statement: "you don't need to give credit for using Android Support Library" ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the link you provided seems to be unrelated here. (It's mentions use of the documentation and code inside it)